# Pods stuck in Init:CrashLoopBackOff state after upgrading the crunchydata PGO from 5.1.2 to 5.3.1 using helm

Tags: kubernetes, upgrade, ansible-playbook, helm

When running the cmd: kubectl get pods -n pgo, it returns.

```
root@XXXXXXXXXXXX:/opt/pgo# kubectl get pods -n pgo. 
NAME                                             READY   STATUS                  RESTARTS         AGE
pgo-b88459754-f6qjq                              1/1     Running                 0          110m
pgo-upgrade-c564d5b74-ph8w8                      1/1     Running                 0          110m
postgres-backup-56rj-qjb87                       0/1     Completed               0          88d
postgres-instance1-x2pq-0                        0/5     Init:CrashLoopBackOff   18         68m
postgres-instance1-ztdb-0                        5/5     Running                 0          68m
postgres-repo-host-0                             2/2     Running                 0          68m
postgres-repo1-diff-28296060-t6n5w               0/1     Completed               0          3d9h
postgres-repo1-diff-28297500-zhjhs               0/1     Completed               0          2d9h
postgres-repo1-diff-28300380-4fpsb               0/1     Completed               0          9h
postgres-repo1-full-28278780-mmxj4               0/1     Completed               0          15d
postgres-repo1-full-28288860-lxs5v               0/1     Completed               0           8d
postgres-repo1-full-28298940-fwhml               0/1     Completed               0          33h
postgres-upgrade-pgdata-ktc7f                    0/1     Completed               0          109m
postgres-upgrade-postgres-instance1-x2pq-nb2xg   0/1     Completed               0          107m
```

When describing the error pod:

```
Normal Created 4s (x3 over 22s) kubelet Created container postgres-startup
Normal Started 4s (x3 over 22s) kubelet Started container postgres-startup
Warning BackOff 3s (x3 over 19s) kubelet Back-off restarting failed container


root@XXXXXXXXXXXX:/opt/pgo# kubectl logs postgres-instance1-x2pq-0 -n pgo -c postgres-startup
Initializing ...
::postgres-operator: uid::26
::postgres-operator: gid::26
::postgres-operator: postgres path::/usr/pgsql-15/bin/postgres
::postgres-operator: postgres version::postgres (PostgreSQL) 15.2
::postgres-operator: config directory::/pgdata/pg15
::postgres-operator: data directory::/pgdata/pg15
::postgres-operator: pgBackRest log directory::/pgdata/pgbackrest/log
::postgres-operator: data version::14
Expected PostgreSQL data version 15
```

But the other instance was running properly and can be able to login to database from that pod and data was copied correctly..

Tried to upgrade crunchydata PGO from 5.1.2 to 5.3.1 using `helm - major version upgrade` by following the link: https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgres-operator/latest/guides/major-postgres-version-upgrade.

How do I make that crashloopback error pod rerun as 5/5 status?